# Can we initialize Base class member struct variable in Derived class

Tags: c++, oop, struct

The question is as above. Let say I have the following code

```
struct Detail{
    int cost;
    int age;
    bool danger;
    unsigned char country=[3];
}

class Toy{
public:
     Toy();
     virtual ~Toy();
};
```

I know that I could initialize Detail struct in the Derived class, say doll, in this manner

```
class doll: public Toy
{
 public:
     doll();
     virtual ~doll();

     Detail detail={4,12,false,"CN"};
};
```

However, I am thinking of how to push Detail struct to the Base class Toy as I have more than one Derived class with differing unique details(the fields of Detail for each Derived are the same but not the value).  This sounded more appropriate to me   as well.

But how could I do an initialization of the struct from Derived class? I am working on c++ by the way

[EDIT]
I intend to place the Derived object ptr into Base class list

Somewhat like this

```
 std::vector<Toy*> toy list;
 doll* one = new doll();
 toy_list.push_back(one);

 Leggo* two = new Leggo(); // another class that Derived from Toy
 toy_list.push_back(two);
```

So that I can eventually use the list to obtain value for individual item

```
  for(auto obj: toy_list)
  {
       printf(" toy is from %d \n", obj->detail.country)
  };
```

Thanks

Comment: *" how to push Detail struct to the Base class Toy..."* What does this mean? The question is unclear.

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain what output you expect and how does it differ from your current output.

Comment: There is nothing in your example (yet) that shows a need for inheritance and you can just use aggregate make details an member of Toy (or even just inject it). Inheritance only will come into play if you want to override virtual methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A derived class can only initialize its own members and direct base classes.

If `detail` is a member of a base class, the base class should provide a
protected constructor able to initialize that member, and the derived
class should use it.

Here is some code showing that. I have made the `detail` member const to prove
that is is only initialized at derived class construction:

```
struct Detail {
    int cost;
    int age;
    bool danger;
    unsigned char country[3];
};

class Toy {
protected:
    Toy(Detail&& detail) : detail(detail) {};

public:
    const Detail detail;

    virtual ~Toy() {};
};

class doll : public Toy
{
public:
    doll() : Toy(Detail{ 4,12,false,"CN" }) {};
    virtual ~doll() {};

};
```

Comment: @Serge_ballesta thanks I am trying out multiple inheritance until I saw this.